# Why isn't Strawberry audio player working in Kubuntu 22.10?

Tags: kubuntu, 22.10, music-player

After clean installation of Kubuntu 22.10 it can be installed from Ubuntu repos but doesn't start at all.

```
~$ strawberry
20:00:23.538 INFO  main:168                         Strawberry 1.0.7 Qt "5.15.6"
20:00:23.538 INFO  main:169                         "Ubuntu 22.10 22.10 - (linux 5.19.0-29-generic) [x86_64]"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Strawberry *was* working in:

- Kubuntu 22.04 LTS
- 22.10, upgraded from LTS & in that 22.10 updated to backports,

It stopped working after I kept upgrading and downgrading, but I am not sure exactly when:

- It still worked after downgrading back to 22.10 from backports, and I even think it still worked after I have upgraded to 23.04 (pre-release) and also after I have succeeded downgrading back to normal 22.10 (!).
- It stopped working after I then updated Kubuntu 22.10 to Plasma 25.27 (Kubuntu beta PPA)!

Of course, at the time, I have imagined that this crazy testing was the cause. But in fact the problem is present after a clean install of 22.10. (I had to do a clean install after the `ppa-purge` downgrade from `kubuntu/beta` failed.)

Installing `kubuntu-restricted-extras` didn't fix it.

(Qmmp seemed affected too, as it could start but couldn't play any file, but that was fixed by adding `options snd_hda_intel index=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/default.conf`, as said [here](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/linux-alsa-lib-pcm_dmix-c1108snd_pcm_dmix_open-unable-to-open-slave-2/))

Other media players are not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is just a bug discussed [HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/strawberry/+bug/1997309), to be fixed in 23.04 Lobster.

The solution proposed for 22.10 is to install from the deb file available [here](https://builds.strawberrymusicplayer.org/ubuntu/kinetic/).

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem.
Using the link to the latest_versions repository @cipricus provided in their answer (copied below) download a .deb file and then do:

```
 $sudo dpkg -i strawberry_1.0.14-49-gfd827fdf-kinetic_amd64.deb
```

which initially fails due to missing packages. However, you need to run it so that the next command completes and adds what's missing.
Run

```
$sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and when that completes rerun the `# dpkg -i straw...`command from above.
That should fix it.

The apt version is old at 1.0.7, versus 1.0.14, and there is no Snap in the Snapstore (the thing that is meant to fix this exact problem by containerizing packages together). The versions on the Strawberry website don't include a 22.10 "Kinetic" Strawberry .deb download. And it doesn't automatically update with `apt dist-upgrade`.

Repository link (tip: sort by 'last modified'):  https://builds.strawberrymusicplayer.org/ubuntu/kinetic/?C=M;O=A

Comment: Also I am on Xubuntu, OP was on Kubuntu, so I think this should work for all Ubuntu flavours, DE agnostic. .